# Set border rounded for list view

Tags: android

I am trying to set rounded border for list view in android. I used shape xml to set background for list view. However, when I click on an item, the highlight is over rounded area.

Is there any ways to overcome this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: i want to display highlight color which is different from background color

Answer (score 1):

This code change your list view as rounded corner

**shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle"> 
     <gradient android:startColor="#SomeGradientBeginColor" android:endColor="#SomeGradientEndColor" 
            android:angle="270"/> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

put is xml file in your drawable folder, the in your listview set like this, `android:background:"@drawable/shape"`

Comment: i tried this, but when u click on first item or last item, highlight color is over on list view